Power BI DAX, multiple columns from different tables into one table
I need to combine columns from four different tables into one summary table. I have one-to-many relationships between these tables. I want to do this using a DAX formula, currently I can drag the different columns into a table visual and I get the expected result but I want to avoid solving the problem in this manner.
I wrote the following formula, at the moment it only shows the columns from the 'purchase_requisition' table. I want to include one column from 'eng_firms', 'business-unit', and 'user' tables. What I tried so far is commented out. When I try adding the columns from the different tables, it tells me the columns either don't exist or the column does not have a relationship to any table available in the current context.
The reason I have the FILTER at the beginning is because the 'purchase_requisition' table has more than 100,000 rows. This table is from a DirectQuery.
I also tried to SUMMARIZECOLUMNS to replace SELECTCOLUMNS, this gave a different error stating that a single value for column [item_delivery_date_lfdat] cannot be determined.
FilteredTable = 
    FILTER(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            CROSSJOIN(
                SELECTCOLUMNS(
                    FILTER(purchase_requisition, purchase_requisition[item_delivery_date_lfdat] = TODAY() && purchase_requisition[flag_goods_service] = "Service" && purchase_requisition[deletion_indicator_in_purchasing_document_loekz] <> "X"),
                    "VendorKey", 'purchase_requisition'[desired_vendor_lifnr], -- relationship with 'eng-firms'[Vendor_number]
                    "PlantKey", 'purchase_requisition'[plant_key], -- relationship with 'business-unit'[plant_key]
                    "User", purchase_requisition[name_of_requisitioner_requester_afnam] --relationship with 'user'[user_identifier]
                ),
                SELECTCOLUMNS(
                    'eng-firms',
                    "VendorNumber", 'eng-firms'[Vendor_number],
                    "Firm", 'eng-firms'[Parent]
                ),
                SELECTCOLUMNS(
                    'business-unit',
                    "BuPlantKey", 'business-unit'[plant_key],
                    "BusinessUnit", 'business-unit'[business_unit.1]
                ),
                SELECTCOLUMNS(
                   'user',
                   "UserIdentity", 'user'[user_identifier],
                   "EmailAddress", 'user'[email_address]
                )
            ),
            "ReqNumber", 'purchase_requisition'[purchase_requisition_number_banfn],
            "ProjectTitle", 'purchase_requisition'[short_text_txz01],
            "DeliveryDate", purchase_requisition[item_delivery_date_lfdat],
            "Firm", 'eng-firms'[Parent],
            "BusinessUnit", 'business-unit'[business_unit.1],
            "EmailAddress", 'user'[email_address]
        ),
        NOT ISBLANK([ReqNumber]) && NOT ISBLANK ([ProjectTitle]) && NOT ISBLANK([DeliveryDate]) && NOT ISBLANK([Firm]) && NOT ISBLANK([BusinessUnit]) && NOT ISBLANK([EmailAddress])
    )

I narrowed the code down to the following to test the CROSSJOIN functionality, and Power BI has been working on it for 1+ hour.

Does your Data Model look like this?
Data Model
Is it the desired output that you want to obtain by using calculated table?
Desired Output

[Update] Perfect! In this case what you really tries to achieve is adding extra columns to the fact table. We know that fact table is connected to all dimensional table with many-to-one relationship, therefore, there is only 1 corresponding row in each dimensional table that we need. Considering the existance of the relationsip, if your model would be in import mode you could sipmly apply this code to obtain the desired result (i.e. getting the corresponding row from dimensional table instead of using crossjoin() ).
FilteredTable = 
VAR _FilterDate = DATE( 2024, 4, 30 )
VAR _ResultTable =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        FILTER(
            purchase_requisition, 
            purchase_requisition[item_delivery_date_lfdat] = _FilterDate && purchase_requisition[flag_goods_service] = "Service" && purchase_requisition[deletion_indicator_in_purchasing_document_loekz] = "X"
        ),
        "ReqNumber", 'purchase_requisition'[purchase_requisition_number_banfn],
        "ProjectTitle", 'purchase_requisition'[short_text_txz01],
        "DeliveryDate", FORMAT( purchase_requisition[item_delivery_date_lfdat], "dd MMMM yyyy" ),
        "Firm", RELATED( 'eng-firms'[Parent] ),
        "BusinessUnit", RELATED( 'business-unit'[business_unit.1] ),
        "EmailAddress", RELATED( 'user'[email_address] )
    )

RETURN _ResultTable

However, the presence of DirectQuery adds to the model "limited relationships" so we can't use Related() fucntion anymore for the creation of calucalted table. Therefore, we replace it with lookup (it's safe to do so because of many-to-one relationship). So the final verison on the code would look like this:
FilteredTable = 
VAR _FilterDate = DATE( 2024, 4, 30 )
VAR _ResultTable =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        FILTER(
            purchase_requisition, 
            purchase_requisition[item_delivery_date_lfdat] = _FilterDate && purchase_requisition[flag_goods_service] = "Service" && purchase_requisition[deletion_indicator_in_purchasing_document_loekz] = "X"
        ),
        "ReqNumber", 'purchase_requisition'[purchase_requisition_number_banfn],
        "ProjectTitle", 'purchase_requisition'[short_text_txz01],
        "DeliveryDate", FORMAT( purchase_requisition[item_delivery_date_lfdat], "dd MMMM yyyy" ),
        "Firm", LOOKUPVALUE( 'eng-firms'[Parent], 'eng-firms'[Vendor_number], purchase_requisition[desired_vendor_lifnr] ), 
        "BusinessUnit", LOOKUPVALUE( 'business-unit'[business_unit.1], 'business-unit'[plant_key], purchase_requisition[plant_key] ),
        "EmailAddress", LOOKUPVALUE( user[email_address], user[user_identifier], purchase_requisition[name_of_requisitioner_requester_afnam] )
    )

RETURN _ResultTable

Here are the screenshots of both outputs:
Import Mode
Direct Query
I hope it helps and good luck with your project!

Yes exactly on both fronts, data model and desired output are correct.

Perfect! I've just updated my initial answer with the solution.
I hope it helps!

I tried to replicate your example with 3 tables and with 2 filters on TableA:

MyTable = 
FILTER(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CROSSJOIN(
            SELECTCOLUMNS(
                FILTER(TableA, TableA[ColA] <> "XXXX"),
                "Id", TableA[Id],
                "ColA_TableA", TableA[ColA]
            ),
            SELECTCOLUMNS(
                TableB,
                "ColB_TableB", TableB[ColB]
            ),
            SELECTCOLUMNS(
                FILTER(TableC, TableC[ColC] = TODAY()),
                "ColC_TableC", TableC[ColC]
            )
        ),
        "ColA", [ColA_TableA],
        "ColB", [ColB_TableB],
        "ColC", [ColC_TableC]
    ),
    NOT ISBLANK([ColA]) && NOT ISBLANK([ColB]) && NOT ISBLANK([ColC])
)


You need to decide which email you use, because if users can have multiple entries in the 'user' table, you will need to refine how you are joining or filtering these tables. :
ADDCOLUMNS(
    CROSSJOIN(...),  
    "EmailAddress", CALCULATE(MIN('user'[email_address]))
)


Thanks for the input. Is ColC correct? I don't see it your model.

ColC is a column text, I didn't expand the table to be displayed. What is the issue so far ?

I edited the code in my post to use the same structure that you suggested. The error currently is the following "A single value for column 'email_address' in table 'user' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result."

I did not find multiple entries in the 'user' table. I believe the CROSSJOIN function is not capable with DirectQuery, the 'purchase_requisition' table is from a DirectQuery and I believe this is causing the problem.

Can you provide some data so I can check ?

No, I can't share the data.

I am trying to find a way to help you.

What is your data source?

I know, I cannot share it, it is company sensitive data. As I said, the problem is not in the data. See the narrowed down formula I added. Power BI does not bring up any error for it but it does not produce result either.

I am asking about the datasource, if it is a database or files ?
because if it is a database, you can use SQL for example

purchase_requisition from database, other tables are added in PowerBi. Only have access to the Power BI dataset, this is why I am hoping to complete it in Power Bi.

How many rows are you dealing with ?

More than 100,000
